# can't write to data.plist file on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have data.plist file on my ios Application I use it to store user preferences. I can read the file. but I can't write the file and I get this error on my catch.

notes: the error happens when I run the app on a test device

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to
>   save the file “data.plist” in the folder “MyApp”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/37FE297E-5801-4681-AA7C-6FCF9BAA9E87/MyApp.app/data.plist,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x283996880 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

```
func updateDataPlist(){

    self.thresholdForAdminBalances = Int(self.txtfThresholdForAdminBalances.text!)
    self.thresholdForSubUserbalances = Int(self.txtfThresholdForSubUserBalances.text!)

    let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormat = .xml

    let preferences =  Preferences(thresholdForAdminBalances: thresholdForAdminBalances!, thresholdForSubUserBalances: thresholdForSubUserbalances!)


    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "plist"){

        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(preferences)
            try data.write(to: path)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don’t have permission to save the file “data.plist” in the folder “MyApp”

Your app's bundle is read-only. Save files in one of the writable directories, e.g. the document or the app support directory.

Use `Filemanager.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` to get the URL for one of those directories.